# Drag'n'drop doesn't work if app launched via python script from windows powershell

Tags: powershell, python3, qt

I have a QT app that I download and launch on Windows. If I launch it manually from Windows Explorer, I can use drag&drop to load files. If I launch the very same app via a python script from windows powershell, invoking it with `subprocess.run(path_to_app_executable)`, drag&drop does not work.

Is it because of using a subprocess? On mac I use `subprocess.run()` with the `open` command and there drag&drop works fine.

Comment: Are you running from a normal or elevated PowerShell window?

Comment: Administrator PowerShell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows systems with UAC have a concept of "integrity levels". Elevated processes (when you use "Run as Administrator") are marked with 'High' integrity level, while normal processes (including your desktop & file manager) run under the 'Medium' level.

Lower-level processes *cannot send data* directly to higher-level processes; in other words, they cannot do anything to corrupt those processes – this is a mitigation of the [Shatter attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack).

But among other things, this also means that they cannot send "window messages" upon which things like drag-and-drop are built.

Comment: Ok, so this means, I can only DnD Admin->Admin and User->User, right? Or would Admin->User also work?